# HP Slate 7 VoiceTab not entering Recovery Mode

Tags: adb, root-access, recovery-mode, fastboot, boot

I have a HP Slate 7 Voicetab running Android 4.4.
I was trying to root it through Kingo Root and then flashing with a custom ROM using TWRP.
But I think I made some mistake and now it won't boot to recovery mode.

- Tried the key combination (Vloume Up + Volume Down + Power), and it opens a Black screen with "Product Mode" written, none of the volume keys work at this page, and long pressing the power key triggers a normal boot.
- Volume Up + Power key doesn't do anything.
- Tried booting to recovery mode through ADB, that doesn't work either.
- Apps like Quick Reboot also failed to boot to recovery menu
- Factory Reset option has also ceased to work. On doing a Factory Reset through settings, it just restarts the device with no change.